# How do I derive a formula for eigenvalues for this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry

Let $\pi$ be a $3\times 3$ orthogonal projection matrix of rank $2$, $H$ be another symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix and $c$ be a constant. Also let $A =\pi H/c$.

Then I wish to show that the non-zero eigenvalues of $\frac{-1}{2c}\pi H\pi$ is given by

$$\kappa_{\pm} = \frac{\text{tr} A \pm \sqrt{2\text{tr}(A^2) - (\text{tr}A)^2  }}{2} \tag{1}$$
, in order to complete my derivation of a formula for principal curvatures for surface.

---

FYI here is the original problem in my homework:

Let $f$ be a smooth real function on an open set $U$ of $\Bbb{E}^3$. Suppose that $X:= f^{-1}(0)$ is non-empty and $df_p \neq 0$ for any $p \in X$. Put
$$\pi = I - \frac{\nabla f(\nabla f)^T}{|\nabla f|^2}, \quad A = \pi \frac{Hf}{|\nabla f|}$$
Prove that $(1)$ is the formula for principal curvatures of the hypersurface $X$.

---

I followed the procedures in the concrete examples given in the book. Here I copy and paste my attempts:

Given $p \in X$, up to rigid motion, assume $p = 0$. Then Taylor formula at $p$ is
\begin{align*} f(p + \vec x) = f(0 + \vec x) &= f(0) + \nabla f(p) \cdot \vec x + \frac{1}{2} \vec x \cdot Hf(p) \vec x + o(|\vec x |^2)\\
0 & = 0 + \underbrace{\frac{\nabla f(p)}{|\nabla f(p)|}}_{\vec n} \cdot \vec x + \frac{1}{2\underbrace{|\nabla f(p)|}_{c}}\vec x  \cdot \underbrace{Hf(p)}_{H} \vec x + o(|\vec x^2|) \\
& = \vec n \cdot \vec x + \frac{1}{2c} \vec x \cdot H \vec x + o(|\vec x|^2)\end{align*}

From linear algebra, $P = \vec n \vec n^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the span of $\vec n$. So the given $\pi = I - \vec n \vec n^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the tangent plane at $p$.

$\vec n   \cdot \vec x $ can be written as $x_3$, which is the coordinate of $\vec x$ along direction $\vec n$.

If $x_1, x_2$ are any orthogonal coordinates on the tangent plane at $p$, up to a rotation around $x_3$ axis, we have $x_3 = \kappa_1x_1^2 + \kappa_2 x_2^2 + o(x_1^2 + x_2^2)$. So that in the quadratic form $\vec x \cdot H\vec x$, further multiplication of $x_1$, $x_2$ or $x_3$ onto $x_3$ would become $o(x_1^2 + x_2^2)$.

So that $\vec x \cdot H\vec x = (\pi \vec x) \cdot H(\pi \vec x) + o(x_1^2  + x_2^2)$, and that

$$ x_3 = - \frac{1}{2c} (\pi \vec x) \cdot H (\pi \vec x) + o(x_1^2 + x_2^2) = - \frac{1}{2c} \vec x^T (\pi^T  H \pi) \vec x + o(x_1^2 + x_2^2) $$

Finally, to remove the crossing term in $- \frac{1}{2c} \vec x^T (\pi^T  H \pi) \vec x $, we have to orthogonally diagonalize the matrix $- \frac{1}{2c} (\pi^T  H \pi)$ and the nonzero entries on the resulting diagonal matrix are the principal curvatures $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$, as shown in that example in the book. But this is just the same as computing the nonzero eigenvalues of the matrix $- \frac{1}{2c} (\pi^T  H \pi)$ and the eigenvalues are found to be...

(Here I need your answers)

---

I also checked with a particular example and found that the nonzero eigenvalues of $\frac{-1}{2c}\pi H\pi$ are really given by $(1)$ and is the principal curvatures of the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can conjugate by an orthogonal matrix to make
$$\pi=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}.$$
So let's do so. Also $H$ remains symmetric; write
$$H=\pmatrix{a&b&d\\b&e&f\\d&f&g}.$$
I'll assume $c=1$ for simplicity (general $c$ will be no harder),
then
$$A=-\pmatrix{a&b&0\\b&e&0\\0&0&0}.$$

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$x(x^2+(a+e)x+ae-b^2).$$
The eigenvalues are zero and
$$\frac{-a-e\pm\sqrt{a^2-2ae+e^2+4b^2}}2$$
But
$$\text{Tr}(A)=-a-e,$$
$$\text{Tr}(A^2)=a^2+e^2+2b^2$$
and so
$$2\text{Tr}(A^2)-\text{Tr}(A)^2=a^2-2ae+e^2+4b^2$$
and your formula drops out.

Comment: Got it! Thanks$ $